# How to pass POST parameters to Chromium via the command line?

Tags: php, linux, post, terminal

I use chromium --ingognito www.mysite.com/page.php?msg=mymessage to open my website and pass it a msg.
I wish to know how to pass the same msg param via POST instead to use GET, from command line.

Comment: in short-- you can't. for more information on why, i would recommend Programming PHP by Kevin Tatroe.

Comment: I know php and I know how to set POST http header with php. My question is how to pass POST params from terminal!

Answer (score 1):

Do you do anything with the site in Chromium after opening it? Otherwise you could use a more capable command line http client like [curl(1)](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) which would make this very easy.

[See this example:](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request)

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://example.com/resource.cgi
```

Comment: if I use curl from terminal it shows me an http answer. My intention is to open request in browser.
How I can to that after chromium opening?

Answer (score 0):

With console ? I don't know, but you can try to use this extension : Advanced REST Client.

*The web developers helper program to create and test custom HTTP requests.*

Here is the link : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo